# Double integral of triangle

Tags: calculus, triangles, vector-analysis

I have this double integral $$I = \int\limits_{}^{} \int\limits_{}^{} y   \ dx \cdot dy$$

and I am supposed to calculate it over a triangle with corners at (0,0),(1,2),(-1,1).
What I did, was splitting the 3 lines that make the triangle to 3 equations of y = 2x, y = -x, y = (x/2)+3/2, but I am not sure how to set the boundaries for these 3 equations.

Can someone explaine me how to set the boundaries in a double integral please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: First decide whether you will integrate over $x$ first or $y$. Say you decide you will integrate over $y$ first then start from left. Write limits of $y$ in terms of $x$ from the equation of two lines that the region is bound by. Then limits of $x$ is $-1$ to $0$. Once you reach y-axis, now the lines $y$ is bound between change. Do the same for $x$ between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Thank you, this is useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guide:

Split the picture into two parts by drawing the line $y=1$.

[image]

For $0\le y \le 1$, the boundary on the right is $x=\frac{y}2$ and the boundary on the left is $x=-y$.  Hence the lower part of the triangle can be written as $$\int_0^1 \int _{-y}^{\frac{y}{2}} y \, dx\, dy$$

Now I will leave the task of describing the upper part of the triangle to you as an exercise.

As a practice, try to interchange the order of integration, consider how should you split the triangle.

Comment: I see, thank you, this helps a lot!